# Testing React component with Jest gives 'Cannot find module' error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a React component using Jest.

The component's code is the following.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Text } from 'components';

class App extends PureComponent {

    static propTypes = {
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        age: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        displayed: PropTypes.bool,
    };

    static defaultProps = {
        displayed: true
    };

    render = () => {
        if (!this.props.displayed) {
            return null;
        }
        const text = `${ this.props.name } is ${ this.props.age } years old.`
        return (
            <span>
                <Text
                    text={ text }
                />
            </span>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

The test code is as simple as this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import App from './../App';

describe('App', () => {
    let props;
    let mountedApp;
    const app = () => {
        if (!mountedApp) {
            mountedApp = mount(
                <App { ...props } />
            );
        }
        return mountedApp;
    };

    beforeEach(() => {
        props = {
            name: 'John',
            age: 35,
            displayed: undefined
        };
        mountedApp = undefined;
    });

    it('always renders a span', () => {
        const spans = app().find('span');
        expect(spans.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
});
```

In my project I am using some Common Components such as Text Component.
All the paths of the Components are set in an index.js file.

File sample code:

```
export Button from 'src/Common/Components/Button';
export Text from 'src/Common/Components/Text';
export Breadcrumb from 'src/Common/Components/Breadcrumb';
```

This is the Jest configuration I am using in package.json file.

```
"jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./Common/Components/setupTests.js",
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "jsx", ""],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "components(.*)$": "<rootDir>/Common/Static/index.js"
    }
  }
```

Webpack alias config:

> alias: {
>       components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Common/Static/index.js'), },

I am running 'npm test' through terminal and the test fails with the following message:

```
Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'src/Common/Components/Button' from 'index.js'

       6 | export Button from 'src/Common/Components/Button';
       7 | export Text from 'src/Common/Components/Text';
    >  8 | export Breadcrumb from 'src/Common/Components/Breadcrumb';
         |                ^

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:210:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (Common/Static/index.js:8:16)
```

All the paths are correct and the code runs smoothly when I remove the test.
I guess that Jest cannot get the paths included in index.js
Is there any suggestion on how to configure Jest to override this problem?

Comment: What does the code of your `Breadcrumb` file look like?

Comment: I noticed in some cases jest doesn't find modules if aliases are used, try making it a relative path instead of alias. Not sure if it's going to work.

Comment: @Aron it is just a custom Breadcrumb Component. As simple as it gets. Even if I remove all the paths except the one that points to Text Component (the one I use) I still get the same kind of error.

Answer (score 3):

I think adding a module path to your jest config will do what you want

```
jest.config.js

module.exports = {
    "modulePaths": [
        "src",
        "test"
    ],
    ...
}
```

edit: Oh your jest config is in package.json, so it should rather be added to your jest entry there

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened for me because the project had configurations in both package.json and jest.config.js

package.json

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^components(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/js/components$1",
    }
}
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom'
};
```

package.json moduleNameMapper appears to be ignored.